# Prove the following identity combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving, factorial, binomial-theorem

Prove the following identity :
a)$$ \binom{n+1}{2m+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-k}{m} \cdot \binom{k}{m} $$
where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers

$\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}$ , for $n\geq m$

and $\binom{n}{m}=0$, for $n<m$

Idea: If we choose $2m+1$ numbers from $n+1$ then one number is in the middle. If this number is $k+1$ then $0\le k\le n$ and we have to choose $m$ numbers to the left to it, ${k\choose m}$ and $m$ numbers to the right of it, ${{n-k}\choose m}$.

How to proceed with this idea?

Comment: What's there to proceed? Isn't that basically already the proof?

Comment: Moreover this proof has been given at this site already.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Where is the proof?

Comment: @Sullo You can search with google, or at this site. See the link given now by Arnaud. This question is quite popular.

Comment: For anyone interested, I found the linked question thanks to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbinom%7Bn%2B1%7D%7B2m%2B1%7D%3D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%20%5Cbinom%7Bn-k%7D%7Bm%7D%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cbinom%7Bk%7D%7Bm%7D%24&p=1).